# Minimum DFA's number of states accepting strings whose length is not a multiple of 9 based on an alphabeth composed by 4 symbols

Tags: automata

How can I calculate the minimum DFA's number of states accepting strings whose length is not multiple of 9 based on an alphabet composed by 4 symbols?

My attempt is:

$L = \{w \in \{a,b,c,d\}^* : \text{9 does not divide |w|}\}$

that means there is not a whole number $z$ such that $|w| = 9\cdot z$

therefore $|w| \in \mathbb{N} - \{9, 18, 27, ...\}$

- How can I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of characters in the alphabet is irrelevant, since you’re interested only in the length of the word. In order to recognize when the length is a multiple of $9$, you need $9$ states, one for each possible remainder. The best that you can do is ring of $9$ states, all of them acceptor states except the initial state. If you’re not sure, start with that DFA and apply the algorithm to minimize it.